# Does resetting network setting wipe your mvno?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers

I want to reset my network setting because i am having a problom with visual voice-mail but i am afraid to do it becaue i do not want it to wipe my [mvno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_virtual_network_operator).

Does it do anything like that?

Comment: What is a MVNO?

Comment: @nohillside - Google says [Mobile virtual network operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_virtual_network_operator) but after reading that I still don't actually know what one is for ;) Resellers of some kind.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah, these are mobile operators without infrastructure who sell plans relying on infrastructure from other operators.

Comment: The US is odd in a lot of ways. Same as out electrical power has a transmission and distribution system, you don’t buy power from them but power resellers. Same with cellular - sprint / AT&T / T-Mobile and Verizon operate most of the actual cellular radios and towers and have peering arrangements - the MVNO buy from the carriers in bulk, and then sell out at a discount. Often they are prepaid, limited in ways that prevent the expected features from working. You can perhaps get what you pay for from MVNO for less than the big carriers, though. More work, less support is typical.

Answer (score 1):

No - resetting network settings just causes your baseband radio to reach out. Unless you have jail broken, this is a very safe and in fact, good thing to do as it forces a proper hand shake and registration with the cellular carriers to the extent you can do that.

Also, it lets you call your carrier and let them know that your issues are not resovled after a reset and reconnection. They can trace your communications from the date/time you reset and then get the issue to their engineering team to help you promptly (we hope).

Comment: Thank you, i have an ATT Mvno and it does not have visual voicemail

Comment: @RobloxGamer101 Bummer - see if they can sell you up or switch carriers when you care to. Some do visual voicemail well for sure.